# realm selectedRowAtIndexPath using segue showing different results

Tags: swift, realm, segue, uisegmentedcontrol

it is my first time using segment control and realm. so currently I am using segue to perform segue to Add/EditVC for modification of data.

when segue performed and took data to Add/EditVC to variable selectedTransaction, I want as following data to to be filled accordingly

```
/* selectedTransaction print statement Results */
print("selectedTransaction = \(selectedTransaction!)")

selectedTransaction = Transaction {
    categoryType = Category {
        type = expense;
        name = EXPENSE 3;
    };
    amount = 1000;
    date = April 2;
}
```

1. amountTF.text = selectedTransaction.amount **(done and correct)**
2. categorySCoutlet.selectedSegmentIndex = selectedTransaction.categoryType.type **(fail to show segmentindex at selectedTransaction.categoryType.type)**
3. categoryTF.text = selectedTransaction.categoryType.name **(name shown correctly, however will return nil if user did not RESELECT again)**

I was expecting all data are shown as if it created.

However, I faced 2 issue in getting it done

1. SegmentControl selected index are always in 0 instead of selectedTransaction.categoryType.name (I want the segment control to be at the index which is as created)
2. categoryTF.text are showing correctly, but if I did not choose again and leave as it be. It will auto return back to nil in results when I pressed the saveButton. : I wish categoryTF.text will return as created and value will not change even if I did not touch it and clicked saveButton

In gif shown below, I chosen row2 as sample. and the result in Realm Browser showing as it is.
I only changed the amountTF.text information from 1200 to 2000, which in result realm browser will set the result of cateogoryType in segmentcontrol to "income" and category will return to nil

[sample of the workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcsRd.gif)

```
//Data Model
//MARK: - Transaction Category Section
 enum CategoryType : String, CaseIterable {
     case income = "income"
     case expense = "expense"

     init?(id : Int) {
         if id < CategoryType.allCases.count {
             self = CategoryType.allCases[id]
         } else {
             return nil
         }
     }
 }



class Category : Object {
    @objc dynamic var type : String = CategoryType.income.rawValue
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""

//    let parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: Transaction.self, property: "ofCategory")
    convenience init(type:CategoryType, name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.type = type.rawValue
        self.name = name
    }

}
```

```
/* VC that should read and load all data to required place */

 //edit
    var selectedTransaction : Transaction!
 @IBOutlet weak var amountTF: UITextField!

    //PickerView for keyboard
    lazy var pickerView : UIPickerView = UIPickerView()
    //Segment Control
    @IBOutlet weak var categorySCoutlet: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryTF: UITextField!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        amountTF.text! = selectedTransaction.amount
        categoryTF.text! = selectedTransaction.categoryType!.name

setupPicker()

    }

    @IBAction func categoryTypeSC(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        guard let type = CategoryType(id: sender.selectedSegmentIndex) else {
            fatalError("error")
        }
        currentCategories = categories.filter("type == %@", type.rawValue)
        categoryTF.text = currentCategories.first?.name
        pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        pickerView.selectRow(1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    }

 //MARK:- Add Transaction Btn
    @IBAction func addTransButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {


    }



    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        if touches.first?.view == view {
            categoryTF.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }


    //MARK:- Picker Helper
    func setupPicker() {
        currentCategories = categories.filter("type == %@", CategoryType.income.rawValue)
        categoryTF.inputView = pickerView

        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self

        categorySCoutlet.setTitle("Income", forSegmentAt: 0)
        categorySCoutlet.setTitle("Expense", forSegmentAt: 1)
        categorySCoutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(categoryTypeSC(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    }
```

Comment: The code to handle the segue should not be within tableView:didSelectRowAt. Also, it looks like your detail controller has a selectedTransaction but selectedAccount is being assigned to it? Or something like that? It's pretty unclear and that's a lot of code of us to parse through. I am not sure I fully understand the question either. Can you clarify the question and code?

Comment: The code in tableView:didSelectRowAt solved my issue in bring the correct data by indexpath to show details in EditVC. If I didn’t put the code, the data being fetch will according to realm database #number. For selectedAccount in AddTransButtonTapped, its to append new transaction according to selectedAccount. Which doesn’t related to this question. Sorry for the confusion I will remove unrelated codes for better understanding.

Comment: Please check the image being attached above for the expected results and issue that being shown inside.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)` in your `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method.

This results in returning the incorrect `indexPath` in `prepareForSegue`.
You should either remove the `deselectRow` call from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method,
or you should create a property to hold the value of `indexPath`.
Something like this:

```
// somewhere in your class
var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?
```

then

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedRowForTrans : Transaction = getTransactions[indexPath.row]
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath // set the value of selectedIndexPath
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if (segue.identifier == "editTrans") {
        if let indexPath = selectedIndexPath { // check if there is a valid indexPath
            let editTransVC = segue.destination as! AddTransactionTableViewController
            let selectedRowForTrans : Transaction = getTransactions[indexPath.row]
            editTransVC.selectedTransaction = selectedRowForTrans

        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Segue did bring the correct information to editTransVC. SegmentControl selected index are always in 0 instead of selectedCategoryType(income/expense) : I want the segment control to be at the index which is as created.
categoryTF.text are showing correctly, but if I did not choose again and leave as it be. It will auto return back to nil in results when I pressed the saveButton. : I wish categoryTF.text will return as created and value will not change even if I did not touch it and clicked saveButton